# proving supremum of sequence is infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

For $j \in \mathbb{N}$ We have $$\|a_n\| \geqq
 \ln\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}$$
gives $\displaystyle
\sup_n\|a_n\|=\infty.$ Hence
$(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge.

> Q1 How to prove $\displaystyle
> \sup_n\|a_n\|=\infty?$

> Q2 Why does $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ not converge?

Comment: Rather confusing ($T_\epsilon$, $ \mathcal{G}_n$,...?). In any case, $\lim_{j\to\infty}\log\frac{j^2+1}{j+1} = +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 has already been answered in the comments. If the norm of $||a_n||$ is bigger than a number that converges to $\infty$ at $n \to \infty$ than the supremum has to be $\infty$ as well because any finite number $a$ being the supremum would imply that $||a_n|| \leq a$ for all $n$ which is not possible because there is an $N_0$ s.t. for all $n \geq N_0$: $\ln(\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}) > a$ because the logarithm is strictly increasing and not bounded and the input $\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$ converges to $\infty$.

As for question 2 there is a theorem that states that a convergent sequence is bounded (which is actually not hard to proof). Now from Question 1 we know that $a_n$ is not bounded because $||a_n|| \leq c$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ is not possible, so $a_n$ is not bounded.